# Swift - JSON Nested Structures get all values with same key names

Tags: json, swift, struct, nested

I'm trying to parse a JSONData, and what I currently get from it, are the values for `date`, `temp` and `text` for the first block inside `channel` array however what I do need is to get all the values with key names `temp`, `text` and `date` including the ones in the second block and I can't figure out the solution.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 2,
    "created": "2017-12-02T15:19:36Z",
    "lang": "fr-fr",
    "results": {
      "channel": [
        {
          "item": {
            "condition": {
              "code": "26",
              "date": "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 05:00 AM AKST",
              "temp": "-1",
              "text": "Cloudy"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "item": {
            "condition": {
              "code": "34",
              "date": "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 08:00 AM CST",
              "temp": "0",
              "text": "Mostly Sunny"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my struct,

```
struct WeatherData {

var temp: String
var climate: String
var date: String

}

extension WeatherData: Decodable {


enum RootKey: String, CodingKey {
    case query

    enum ResultsKey: String, CodingKey {
        case results, count, lang, created

        enum ChannelKey: String, CodingKey {
            case channel

            enum ItemKey: String, CodingKey {
                case item

                enum ConditionKey: String, CodingKey {
                    case condition

                    enum WeatherConditions: String, CodingKey {
                        case temp
                        case text
                        case date
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
 let query = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootKey.self)
 let results = try query.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootKey.ResultsKey.self, forKey: .query)
 let channel = try results.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootKey.ResultsKey.ChannelKey.self, forKey: .results)
 var itemContainerUnidentified = try channel.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .channel)
 let itemContainerIdentified = try itemContainerUnidentified.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootKey.ResultsKey.ChannelKey.ItemKey.self)
 let condition = try itemContainerIdentified.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootKey.ResultsKey.ChannelKey.ItemKey.ConditionKey.self, forKey: .item)
 let weather = try condition.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RootKey.ResultsKey.ChannelKey.ItemKey.ConditionKey.WeatherConditions.self, forKey: .condition)
    temp = try weather.decode(String.self, forKey: .temp)
    date = try weather.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
    climate = try weather.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a different (classic) approach with multiple structs and without custom initializer

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let query : Query
    var channels : [Channel] {
        return query.results.channel
    }
}

struct Query : Decodable {
    let count : Int
    let created : Date
    let lang : String
    let results : Results
}

struct Results : Decodable {
    let channel : [Channel]
}

struct Channel : Decodable {
    let item : [String : Condition]
}

struct Condition : Decodable {
    let code : String
    let date : String
    let temp : String
    let text : String
}
```

and print all values for `code`, `date`, `temp` and `text` in the `channel` array

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "query": {
        "count": 2,
        "created": "2017-12-02T15:19:36Z",
        "lang": "fr-fr",
        "results": {
            "channel": [{"item": { "condition": { "code": "26", "date": "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 05:00 AM AKST", "temp": "-1", "text": "Cloudy"}}},
                        {"item": { "condition": { "code": "34", "date": "Sat, 02 Dec 2017 08:00 AM CST", "temp": "0", "text": "Mostly Sunny"}}}]
        }
    }
}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
for channel in root.channels {
    for (_, condition) in channel.item {
        print(condition.code)
        print(condition.date)
        print(condition.temp)
        print(condition.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and the code is much more readable! thank you!